# Is it bad practice if I inject Serilog from Startup.cs and not from Program.cs?

Tags: c#, .net, dependencies, code-injection, serilog

I'm trying to configure Serilog in a .NET 5 WebApi project.

I can't figure out why everyone is injecting Serilog in `Program.cs`, and not in the `Startup.cs` file like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // inject serilog logger.
            services.AddScoped<ILogger>(factory =>
            {
                return new LoggerConfiguration()
                            .WriteTo.File(@"C:\mylogs\log.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
                            .CreateLogger();

            });

            services.AddControllers();
        }
```

Comment: Could you give an example of everyone doing it in Program.cs? Because I do it in Startup.cs. Maybe I'm wrong too, so I'm curious as to where you're seeing alternatives.

Comment: Hi, all I can find are these steps:

https://nblumhardt.com/2019/10/serilog-in-aspnetcore-3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you register `Logger` in DI instead of configuring `ILoggerFactory`, you're not guaranteed that all your dependencies will use the one you registered in the `startup.cs`.

In the below issue, it's exactly what happened when OP configured that in the `startup.cs`
[.Net Core EventLog - override unhandled exception are written to Application log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67074353/net-core-eventlog-override-unhandled-exception-are-written-to-application-log/67078020#67078020)

Comment: Thank you very much!